# Image hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to set in table cell the image and this image should be changed with hover action.

The css file:

```
#image_background  { background-image: url(images/panorami_gallery.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
...
}

.left_button { background-image: url (images/left_gallery_arrow.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.left_button:hover { background-image: url (images/left_gallery_arrow_hover.png);
           background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

The html-file:

```
<table id="background_image">
....
    <tr>
       <td>
          <div class ="left_button">
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem that I don't see the "left_gallery_arrow.png" image at all. What does I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot have a space between url and the braces... `url (...)` is wrong.. `url()` is correct.  (Chrome + Ubuntu anyways)

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/TwcQS/

you div needs a height and width property to display the image.. or content.

also i'm assuming #image_background is meant to reference the table... typo? should be `#background_image`

Answer (score 0):

The div has no content and no explicit height or width. There is no collection of pixels for the background image to be painted on.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I changed it to <div class="left_button" height ="140" width="30"> , but still I have an bug. Maybe the arrow image is not in the front of the table background image?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that something like it exists. I should to study to use it, it looks nice.